# Bump function on set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Given an arbitrary compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and an open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, I want to construct a bump function $\zeta$  that is $1$ on $K$ and has its support in $V$, where I assume that $K \subset  V$. Also it would be good to have $0 \le \zeta\le 1$ everywhere.

Could anybody give me a reference or explain to me how I can construct such a function?

Comment: Evans PDEs and Lee introduction to smooth manifolds.

Comment: @TKM on which page in Evans book? -Cannot find it

Comment: I think it's an exercise in Evans, Chapter 5. Though it may also be in the appendix, where he talks about convolutions.

Comment: @TobiasHurth : I think you mean $K\subset V$ instead of the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These bump functions, or test functions, are extremely important in distribution theory. They can be constructed using partitions of unity. I didn't find any good references online in this context, but if you can get hold of Hörmanders ``The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I'', then it's an excellent reference.

Comment: well, the partition of unity is rather the existence proof, don't you think so?

Comment: Doesn't the subsection "construction of bump functions" on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) does exactly what the op asked for?